# Server Error in '/' Application. Keyword not supported

Tags: .net, sql-server

I am trying to connect to a database and have been looking for a way to solve this error

Keyword not supported:

```
select first_name + ' ' + last_name as name
  ,position_descr
  ,staff_bio 
from dbo.staff_bios b
join dbo.staff_position_lk p
  on b.position_id= P.Staff_Position_ID
                        Where Staff_Bios_ID = @StaffBiosID
                          AND Effective_Date = (Select MAX(Effective_Date) 
                                               From EyeCareForYou.dbo.Staff_Bios
                       Where Staff_Bios_ID = @StaffBiosID)'.
```

Description:

> An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code.

Exception Details:

> System.ArgumentException: Keyword not supported: 'select first_name + ' ' + last_name as name
>                              ,position_descr
>                              ,staff_bio 
>                              from dbo.staff_bios b
>                              join dbo.staff_position_lk p
>                              on b.position_id P.Staff_Position_ID
>                               Where Staff_Bios_ID = @StaffBiosID
>                                 AND Effective_Date = (Select MAX(Effective_Date) 
>                                                      From EyeCareForYou.dbo.Staff_Bios
>                              Where Staff_Bios_ID = @StaffBiosID)'.

This is from my web.config

```
<appSettings>  
  <add key="SqlSelect" value="Data Source=mysource; Initial Catalog=EyeCareForYou; User ID=EyeCareForYou; Password='mypassword';" />
</appSettings>
<connectionStrings>
  <add name="SqlSelect" connectionString="Data Source=mysource; Initial Catalog=EyeCareForYou; User ID=myuserid; Password='mypassword';"/>
</connectionStrings>`
```

I have tried a number of things. Help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: It looks like your SQL is incorrect... can you show use where that SQL `SELECT` is being called?

Comment: Put some space inside the quotes and try select first_name + '  ' + last_name as name

Comment: Try escaping `name` (i.e. make it `last_name AS [Name]`).

Comment: SHow us the full select statement as this seems to be missing code at the end (like the rest of the join condition).

Comment: I updated the sql to show the whole select statement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try following:

- Remove `‘.` from the end of the query ;
- Check your connection string – quotes are not needed around password;
- Change `as name` to `as [Name]`.

For extra points do the following:

- Remove database name from this part `EyeCareForYou.dbo.Stuff_Bios`;
- Qualify column names to make your query more readable. Replace `first_name` with `b.first_name`.

Last two are not required but they will make your code cleaner. 
Use database name in queries only when you’re making queries that use data from multiple databases.

If this doesn’t help then post your complete .NET code.

Answer (score 0):

Your SQL is incomplete , you are missing the join condition.it should be like :-

```
select first_name + ' ' + last_name as name
  ,position_descr
  ,staff_bio 
from dbo.staff_bios b
join dbo.staff_position_lk p
  on b.position_id=p.position_id
```

Also Remove single quote in password in web config:-

```
<appSettings>  
  <add key="SqlSelect" value="Data Source=mysource; Initial Catalog=EyeCareForYou; User ID=EyeCareForYou; Password=mypassword;" />
</appSettings>
<connectionStrings>
  <add name="SqlSelect" connectionString="Data Source=mysource; Initial Catalog=EyeCareForYou; User ID=myuserid; Password=mypassword;"/>
</connectionStrings>
```